# Taking single value from a grouped data frame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am a new Python convert (from Matlab). I am using the pandas `groupby` function, and I am getting tripped up by a seemingly easy problem. I have written a custom function that I `apply` to the grouped df that returns 4 different values. Three of the values are working great, but the other value is giving me an error. Here is the original `df`:

```
Index,SN,Date,City,State,ID,County,Age,A,B,C
0,32,9/1/16,X,AL,360,BB County,29.0,negative,positive,positive
1,32,9/1/16,X,AL,360,BB County,1.0,negative,negative,negative
2,32,9/1/16,X,AL,360,BB County,10.0,negative,negative,negative
3,32,9/1/16,X,AL,360,BB County,11.0,negative,negative,negative
4,35,9/1/16,X,AR,718,LL County,67.0,negative,negative,negative
5,38,9/1/16,X,AR,728-13,JJ County,3.0,negative,negative,negative
6,38,9/1/16,X,AR,728-13,JJ County,8.0,negative,negative,negative
7,30,9/1/16,X,AR,728-13,JJ County,8.0,negative,negative,negative
8,30,9/1/16,X,AR,728-13,JJ County,14.0,negative,negative,negative
9,30,9/1/16,X,AR,728-13,JJ County,5.0,negative,negative,negative
...
```

This is the function that transforms the data. Basically, it counts the number of 'positive' values and the total number of observations in the group. I also want it to return the ID value, and this is where the problem is:

```
def _ct_id_pos(grp):
    return grp['ID'][0], grp[grp.A == 'positive'].shape[0], grp[grp.B == 'positive'].shape[0], grp.shape[0]
```

I  `apply` the `_ct_id_pos` function to the data grouped by `Date` and `SN`:

```
FullMx_prime = FullMx.groupby(['Date', 'SN']).apply(_ct_id_pos).reset_index()
```

So, the method should return something like this:

```
     Date  SN   ID       0
0  9/1/16  32  360  (360,2,1,4)
1  9/1/16  35  718  (718,0,0,1)
2  9/2/16  38  728  (728,1,0,2)
3  9/3/16  30  728  (728,2,0,3)
```

But, I keep getting the following error:

```
...
KeyError: 0
```

Obviously, it does not like this part of the function: `grp['ID'][0]` . I just want to take the first value of `grp['ID']` because--if there are multiple values--they should all be the same (i.e., I could take the last, it does not matter). I have tried other ways to index, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `grp['ID'][0]` to `grp.iloc[0]['ID']`

The problem you are having is due to `grp['ID']` which selects a column and returns a `pandas.Series`.  Which is straight forward enough, and you could reasonably expect that `[0]` would select the first element.  But the `[0]` actually selects based on the index for the Series, and in this case the index is from the dataframe that was grouped. So, `0` is not always going to be a valid index.

**Code:**

```
def _ct_id_pos(grp):
    id = grp.iloc[0]['ID']
    a = grp[grp.A == 'positive'].shape[0]
    b = grp[grp.B == 'positive'].shape[0]
    sz = grp.shape[0]

    return id, a, b, sz
```

**Test Code:**

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(u"""
    Index,SN,Date,City,State,ID,County,Age,A,B,C
    0,32,9/1/16,X,AL,360,BB County,29.0,negative,positive,positive
    1,32,9/1/16,X,AL,360,BB County,1.0,negative,negative,negative
    2,32,9/1/16,X,AL,360,BB County,10.0,negative,negative,negative
    3,32,9/1/16,X,AL,360,BB County,11.0,negative,negative,negative
    4,35,9/1/16,X,AR,718,LL County,67.0,negative,negative,negative
    5,38,9/1/16,X,AR,728-13,JJ County,3.0,negative,negative,negative
    6,38,9/1/16,X,AR,728-13,JJ County,8.0,negative,negative,negative
    7,30,9/1/16,X,AR,728-13,JJ County,8.0,negative,negative,negative
    8,30,9/1/16,X,AR,728-13,JJ County,14.0,negative,negative,negative
    9,30,9/1/16,X,AR,728-13,JJ County,5.0,negative,negative,negative
    """), header=0, index_col=0)

print(df.groupby(['Date', 'SN']).apply(_ct_id_pos).reset_index())
```

**Results:**

```
     Date  SN                  0
0  9/1/16  30  (728-13, 0, 0, 3)
1  9/1/16  32     (360, 0, 1, 4)
2  9/1/16  35     (718, 0, 0, 1)
3  9/1/16  38  (728-13, 0, 0, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked! Can you explain why I need to index with iloc? I.e., why didn't the way I did it initially work?

Comment: One of the great strengths of `pandas` is that it works really hard to just do the right thing in an amazing number of cases, but this leads to some intellectual ambiguity.  One case of which you bumped into.

Comment: This means there is some learning curve, but that is traded against a very productive environment once you get rolling with it. Good news is that `pandas` if quite well supported here on SO.  I am at best a member of the B team, the A team is very active during the work week, and well constructed questions are generally answered in short order. As to the initial lack of explanation of the *why* to the answer, thank you for calling me on it.  I should have included more explanation in the initial answer.  I have updated the answer with some *why*.  Good luck....

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That would have never occurred to me, but it makes sense. Thanks again, I appreciate it!